# Python datetime to day and time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to extract day and time from a datetime index of a dataframe.

My code:

```
df.index = DatetimeIndex(['2020-07-07 19:03:38', '2020-07-08 18:50:40',
                '2020-07-24 4:20:13', '2020-07-25 4:20:13'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='datetime', freq=None)

print(df.index.strftime('%d %h:%m')
```

Is there a default way to get this like `.date` approach?

Comment: _extract day and time_ means `df.index.day` and `df.index.time`, it does not mean, to remove. If the question, means something else, it should be clarified. Also, it's `df.index.strftime('%d %H:%M')`, not `h` and `m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `pd.to_datetime` rather than the `DatetimeIndex`. And as Trenton McKinney pointed out in the comments it should be `H` and `M` in the `strftime`:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = {'stuff': [0,1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(['2020-07-07 19:03:38', '2020-07-08 18:50:40',
                '2020-07-24 4:20:13', '2020-07-25 4:20:13']).strftime('%d %H:%M')
                
print(df)

          stuff
07 19:03      0
08 18:50      1
24 04:20      2
25 04:20      3
```